# Android APK - Set app category

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk, categories

I've created an Android app using Qt. I was wondering if one can set a category for the app (eg: communication, navigation, office, media player, education, etc) that will place the icon under a certain tab in you application drawer after installation (if the launcher supports it), similar to how Ubuntu categorizes the programs. Currently my app is automatically added to a category "null".

I've noticed the `<category>` tag in the AndroidManifest documentation. But that does not seem to be it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe when you upload your apk in Play you can set the category, though not sure how the launcher would use that information

Comment: Unfortunately this information is only provided on the web interface and therefore is not part of the downloaded apk.

Comment: Yes, I don't think the category on Google Play will have and affect here. I noticed that the smaller apps mostly don't have this. But bigger apps, like Firefox are automatically added in your "Internet" category if you have one. Or my Whatsapp was added to my "Communication" category.

Answer (score 0):

Some Launchers may just have hardcoded a link between most popular applications and categories (e.g. they hardcoded Firefox app to appear in the 'Internet' category). This would explain why it happens to bigger apps mostly in case of your launcher.

However, as you pointed out, there's a `<category>` tag you may use in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Categories that may be used by such launchers typically start with `CATEGORY_APP` prefix.

What happens if you associate your main activity with a `CATEGORY_APP_MESSAGING` for example (Manifest's constant: android.intent.category.APP_MESSAGING)? Does is land in the same category as WhatsApp then?